# woocommerce recalculate price programmatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**11/5/21 Update**

It's really tricky that find out the `wc_order` couldn't access the calculate_totals and calculate_taxes.I find out the solution is put `$order = wc_get_order( $order->get_id() );` before calulation. The 2 $order type is different , one is `(object)WC_Order` and another one is `(Object)Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\Overrides\Order`. The method of second object works.

I wanna make the AJAX function to place an order programmatically. The product price is base on metadata so I have to calculate every line item. It doesn't with any issue from the client side that sends the post the request to place. The problem point, even I set the price to the line item, and use `calculate_totals` for the `WC_Order` but the price didn't correct. The only correction is the cost and subtotal. Though I hit the recalculate button the price would be right.

**code**

```php
function place_an_order($data){

  $screen_prodcut = new WC_Product_Simple(6310);

  $userid = get_current_user_id();
  $order = wc_create_order(array('customer_id'=>$userid));

  $screen_quantity = 2;
  $item_id =  $order->add_product($screen_prodcut,$screen_quantity);
  wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id,'width','1201');
  wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id,'height','1201');
  wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id,'note','** this is testing**');

  $screen_price = 50;
  $new_line_screen_price = $screen_price * $screen_quantity; 
  $item = $order->get_item($item_id);
  $item->set_subtotal( $new_line_screen_price / 11 * 10 ); 
  $item->set_total( $new_line_screen_price / 11 * 10 );
  $item->save();
  // ###section 1###
  $order->calculate_taxes();
  $order->calculate_totals(); 
  // ###section 2###
}
```

When run in `section 1`, the `$item` subtotal and total are correct. But run in `section 2` there is the failure out when printing `$order` and retrieve the total is wrong. In the dashboard, the price would be shown wrong but the total and subtotal are correct.

[image]

After clicking the `recalculate`, the order total is corrected.

[image]

I have no idea why `calculate_totals` and `calculate_taxes` don't work. [woocommerce_calc_line_taxes](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_ajaxcalc_line_taxes/) is the AJAX action via hit the recalculate button. Usage is calculate_totals and taxes as well. Alternatively, I have to use the `set_total` instead of `calculate_totals`?